# script as module and executable

Tags: python

- I have a script in python that can be invoked from the command-line and uses `optparse`.

  ```
  script -i arg1 -j arg2
  ```

  In this case I use `(options, args) = parser.parse_args()` to create `options` then use `options.arg1` to get arguments.
- But I also want it to be importable as a module.

  ```
  from script import *
  function(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2)
  ```

  I've managed to do this using a really lame solution: by providing a dummy object.

  ```
  def main():
      class Options:
          ''' dummy object '''
          def __init__(self):
              pass
      options = Options
      for k in kwargs:
          setattr(options, k, kwargs[k])
  ```

The rest of the script doesn't know the difference but I think this solution is fugly.

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: `for k in **kwargs:`? can you paste the actual code you are using?

Comment: That's actually not a bad solution.  Just FYI though, you can remove the __init__ and just have "class Options: pass".  I've often wondered why Python doesn't come with a built-in "null class" that lets you set any attributes on it, as you can't do with a plain `object()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Separate the CLI from the workhorse class:

```
class Main(object):
    def __init__(self,arg1,arg2):
        ...
    def run(self):
        pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    import optparse
    class CLI(object):
        def parse_options(self):
            usage = 'usage: %prog [options]'+__usage__
            parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage=usage)
            parser.add_option('-i', dest='arg1')
            parser.add_option('-j', dest='arg2') 
            (self.opt, self.args) = parser.parse_args()
        def run(self):
            self.parse_options()        
            Main(self.opt.arg1,self.opt.arg2).run()
    CLI().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

What you usually do is:

```
def foo():
    print 'This is available when imported as a module.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'This is executed when run as script, but not when imported.'
```